# Using action listeners on Jbutton array from another class / StackOverflowError

Tags: java

I am making a Yahtzee type program. It is for my final project in my Java class. I have a it broken up into multiple classes. The part I am having trouble with is between my ScoreSheet class and ScoreControl class.

ScoreSheet uses a method with a loop that adds an array of JButtons and adds action listeners to them. I then add the action listener to the ScoreControl class. However when I reference the array in the ActionPerformed, I don't get any output. Here is my relevant code:

From ScoreSheet: (the (sc) is the name of my ScoreControl)

```
public void setupUpperButtons(){
    for(int i = 0; i<NUM_UPPER_CATEGORIES; i++){
        upperCategories[i] = new JButton(upperNames[i]);
        upperCategories[i].addActionListener(sc);
        upperCategories[i].setFocusPainted(false);
    }
```

When I try to reference a button from the array, (in the ScoreControl class) like so:

```
 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == sheet.upperCategories[0]) {
            System.out.println("You have pressed a button");
        }
```

I don't get any output. The print is just to test if it's working, obviously different stuff will go there once I get it to work.

I just noticed that in my ScoreSheet, I have

```
ScoreControl=sc;
```

But in the constructor I do not have

```
sc = new ScoreControl;
```

But when I add that line in, I get a huge stack of StackOverflow error.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at sun.applet.AppletSecurity.checkPackageAccess(AppletSecurity.java:281)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.checkPackageAccess(ReflectUtil.java:188)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUIClass(UIDefaults.java:680)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getUI(UIDefaults.java:757)
at javax.swing.UIManager.getUI(UIManager.java:1016)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
at ScoreSheet.<init>(ScoreSheet.java:33)
at ScoreControl.<init>(ScoreControl.java:16)
at ScoreSheet.<init>(ScoreSheet.java:34)
at ScoreControl.<init>(ScoreControl.java:16)
at ScoreSheet.<init>(ScoreSheet.java:34) (these last two lines repeat many many times)
```

Here is each constructor:

from ScoreSheet:

```
public ScoreSheet(){
    sc = new ScoreControl();
    grid = new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 3);
    setupUpperSection();
    setupLowerSection();
    setupFields();
    setupScorePanel();
    setupScoreSheet();
}
```

From ScoreControl:

```
 public ScoreControl() {
    sheet = new ScoreSheet();
}
```

I am just starting work on my ScoreControl, so other stuff will go in there later but that's how they are currently.

Comment: Unfortunately, what little code you have posted looks fine.  You'll have to edit the question to provide more code, ideally a [mcve], for us to provide any useful help.  Otherwise, all we can suggest is adding debug statements, like `System.out.println(e.getSource())` and comparing those values to `System.out.println(upperCategories[i])`, and see if they match.

Comment: I will do this, thank you.

Comment: Now it looks like you've got some mutual recursion going on.  Your ScoreSheet is creating a ScoreControl, which is creating a _new_ ScoreSheet, which creates a _new_ ScoreControl, and so on, ad infinitum.  You need to pass a reference of one into the constructor of the other, so it doesn't need to create it, but rather uses the instance it is given.  Add your constructors to your post for more detailed help.

Comment: I couldn't help but laugh at myself when you explained what is happening. Thank you. I just re-edited my post. I mostly understand what you say at the end, the solution, but I am too new to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple fix.  You just need to pass the `ScoreSheet` instance to the `ScoreControl` constructor.

```
public ScoreSheet(){
    sc = new ScoreControl(this);
    grid = new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 3);
    setupUpperSection();
    setupLowerSection();
    setupFields();
    setupScorePanel();
    setupScoreSheet();
}

public ScoreControl(ScoreSheet _sheet) {
    sheet = _sheet;
}
```

You can also do this in the opposite way ...

```
public ScoreSheet(ScoreControl _sc){
    sc = _sc;
    grid = new GridLayout(0, 1, 10, 3);
    setupUpperSection();
    setupLowerSection();
    setupFields();
    setupScorePanel();
    setupScoreSheet();
}

public ScoreControl() {
    sheet = new ScoreSheet(this);
}
```

But understand that the construction of `ScoreControl` is not complete while the `ScoreSheet` is being constructed.  If any of the methods called in `ScoreControl` constructor reference `sc`, `sc.sheet` will not yet be initialized, because `new ScoreSheet(this)` has not yet returned a value.

Since `ScoreControl` constructor doesn't call any methods, it just stores a reference to `ScoreSheet`, I prefer the former method.